# How to provide a Redux store to Remix JS project?

Tags: react-redux, remix.run

I've been following closely Remix Run JS (https://remix.run/) and I've been working with some tutorials, however, I haven't found anywhere here or in the web of how to implement a redux store:

I was thinking in wrapping the `App` component like this but I'm not sure if that's how it should be done:

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <meta charSet="utf-8" />
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
          <Meta />
          <Links />
        </head>
        <body>
          <Link to="/posts">Posts</Link>
          <Outlet />
          <ScrollRestoration />
          <Scripts />
          {process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" && <LiveReload />}
        </body>
      </html>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: I am curious why you need redux at all? Or if you do have a complex state management requirement for your app, why do you want to use Remix? Remix as a framework tries to avoid this sort of client side state management. See their blog post about data flow for example: https://remix.run/blog/remix-data-flow

Comment: As you mentioned, it all depends on your needs. I usually work with complex states  in my apps and therefore require libraries such as redux (Zustand sometimes works too), and while playing with Remix I got curious about a possible Redux implementation for it. Loaders work in 90% of the use cases tbh.

Comment: Redux has its uses, but as @hakeri mentioned, you don't really need redux and as Remix tries to remove all of that state complexity.

Comment: Sorry, I still think that redux is needed in "some" cases. Most of the time that should be covered with `loaders/useContext`, but I still think that this is a valid —probably not usual— use case.

Comment: Imagine the following: You got a huge application based on a lot of things. The User experience divides into a lot of clients. There is for example a webapp a native app and an desktop application. They'r all using the same entities and working with the same logic, each of them was build with Typescript. Why should i reimplement the logic for each application if i could just use a state management install it and share logic and even test logic together ?

Comment: obvious use case: local first app with redux connected to indexeddb or wasm sqlite

Answer (score 1):

I've got the redux store to work on client navigation & ssr by doing the following:

Try selecting and loading a global store in `entry.client.js`:

```js
import store from './store/store';

startTransition(() => {
  
  if(typeof window.globalStore === 'undefined'){
    window.globalStore = store;
  }

  hydrateRoot(
    document,
    <StrictMode>
      <Provider store={window.globalStore}>
        <RemixBrowser />
      </Provider>
    </StrictMode>
  );
});
```

And load the default initial store in `app/root.tsx`:

```js
...
import store from './store/store';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <Meta />
        <Links />
      </head>
      <body>

      <Provider store={store}>
        <Outlet />
        <ScrollRestoration />
        <Scripts />
        <LiveReload />
      </Provider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

**Note that you might have to:**

- merge state of data from `loader` between client navigation
- utilize `clientRouter` to make loader logic optional / fetch only if data not already in store ( I'm not sure how to best do this & curious myself - let me know & I'll update my answer )

Answer (score 0):

in app/root.tsx you can add it like that

```
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {store} from '~/redux/store'; 
.....

export default function App() {
const nonce = useNonce();
const data = useLoaderData<typeof loader>();
return (
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charSet="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <Meta />
    <Links />
  </head>
  <body>
    <Provider store={store}> // here
      <Layout {...data}>
        <Outlet />
      </Layout>
    </Provider>
    <ScrollRestoration nonce={nonce} />
    <Scripts nonce={nonce} />
    <LiveReload nonce={nonce} />
  </body>
</html>);
}
```

Comment: store does not seem to be preserved on navigation. store gets preserved on navigation if you put the provider in entry.client.tsx however the later creates another issue on page refresh